# GridView does not change on page change

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-binding, gridview

Gridview: Data does not change on page change.

Hi, im working on a asp.net website with c#.
I have a gridview with paging, the gridview is populated from an sql database, and on the PageIndexChanging I have:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    BindGridControl();

    gridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gridView.DataBind();
}
```

If I click on page 2 for example, the next rows of data display fine.
But if I click back to the page 1, the data does not change, it keep displaying the data from the page 2.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
   gridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
   BindGridControl();  
   gridView.DataBind();
}
```

Is your BindGridControl() load the data and set it to your gridView datasource?

Comment: Yes. BindGridControl() is a method made by me. And sets the data to the gridview datasource.

Comment: I tried the changes you posted but it doesn't work... What can I do?

Comment: May i have BindGridControl() in details

Comment: This is the  BindGridControl() method:::::`code   protected void BindGridControl()
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connection].ConnectionString);
SqlDataReader dr;
 SqlCommand cmd;
 cmd = new SqlCommand();
 cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.CommandText = "sp_load";
        sqlConn.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
     GridView1.DataBind();
        sqlConn.Close();
    } `

Comment: Im also using the GridView1_RowDataBound event to load data to the gridview

Comment: you are binding twice. Please remove  GridView1.DataBind();  from BindGridControl() method. gridView.DataBind(); should be the last item..

Comment: do you have two gridview by any case... GridView1 and gridView?

Comment: If I remove GridView1.DataBind(); from the  BindGridControl() method, and I get no values on page load for the gridview. The method is also called on page load: `code  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGridControl();

        } `.........And I dont have two gridviews, I only miswrote it. The correct one is GridView1, it is the only one Im using.

Comment: protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
   gridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
   BindGridControl();     
}

Comment: With these changes, if I click to page 2, or page 3 the data does not change. The data is the same as in page 1.

Comment: It seems the problem is with the GridView1_RowDataBound event. I have a counter(an int variable) there and it resets itself every time the user clicks on a new page link. That's why i get the same values again.

Comment: this is my counter:...... `code int c1; protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dd.Text = dt.Rows[c1]["Code"].ToString();
                    c1++;
}
} `
............I did it this way to iterate through the rows. The problem is, it is reseting itself as I said. Which alternative can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse order of instructions

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

    gridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

        BindGridControl();

    gridView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I did these changes. But the problems remains.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too for a long time. 
I came up with this and it finally works for me.

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    BindGridControl(e.NewPageIndex);
}
```

And then in your BindGridControl function:

```
protected void BindGridControl(int pageNumber = 0)
{ 
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connect‌​ion].ConnectionStrin‌​g);
    SqlDataReader dr;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_load";
    sqlConn.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
    GridView1.PageIndex = pageNumber;
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    sqlConn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

    gridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    BindGridControl();

    DataBind();
}
```